# Why LED bulbs doesn't work?

Tags: light-fixture, led

I bought London 3 light lamp and put 3 LED bulbs 6W.
and doesn't work. Only when I switch on then flashed for second but only 3 times. Normal lamp works without problem. There is 2 cables. 1 cable to one bulb  when connect only this cable lamp glow.
When connect only second cable that connect 2 bulbs. Don't work.
I was thinking tha lamp is faulty and bought another one but another lamp didn't work also. 
When I connected lamp to wall outlet lamp work perfectly. 
When I changed to normal bulbs lamp worked. 
When I have 2 terminal LED bulbs and  3rd middle one normal - lamp works.
I need to add that lamp is connected to 2 way switch. 
That's very strange problem, maybe someone know the answer. 
Thanks Artur [image][image]

Comment: How exactly did you connect the wires when you tried multiple lamps? Series or parallel? Draw us a diagram of what you did.

Comment: What type of switch? Electronic switches not listed for use with led’s Sometimes do exactly what you describe. Getting a switch listed for use with LED’s will probably solve your problem. If properly wired.

Comment: Were there LEDs in the previous light?

Comment: I have a similar problem with an outdoor light. I think it simply does not work with LEDs (hard wired to power). It is a motion detection light though